# Занесение файлов в ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, контроль-версий

Может кто знает, как рекурсивно занести файлы на ветку в ClearCase? Т.е мы берем верхнюю папку и указываем только ее, а все, что внутри, заносится автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

Из терминала - командой [clearfsimport](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm). Наверное, и из оболочки как-то можно.